# Eigenspace of linear completely continuous field

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, spectral-theory

> Let $H_1$ and $H$ be Hilbert spaces, and $H_1 \subset H$ be a dense and compact inclusion. A linear operator $L: H_1 \to H$ is called a *completely continuous field* if $L = - A + B$, where $A: H_1 \to H$ is a linear homeomorphism and $B: H_1 \to H$ is a linear compact operator.
>
> **Theorem**: The eigenspace of $L$ is of finite dimension.

The result is quite similar to compact operator cases, but I am not able to use a similar method to prove it. Could anyone give me some hint on this?

Edit: These are from Section 3.1 of the book "Birfucation theory and applications" by Ma and Wang, and the corresponding paragraphs are attached:
[image]
[image]

Comment: How does $L$ relate to the inclusion $H_1\to H$? As it stands letting $H_1= \ell^2(\Bbb N) = H$, for which a compact inclusion $(x_n)_n \mapsto (2^{-n}x_n)_n$ exists. Then $L = -\Bbb1 +0$ is of the form you specify with the eigenspace of $-1$ being infinite dimensional.

Comment: @s.harp I think the compact inclusion should mean that the identity map is compact, i.e., a bounded sequence in $H_1$ has a convergent subsequence in $H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the question is to be understood like this:

> Let $i: H_1\to H$ be a compact injection with dense image. An eigenvector of a map $L: H_1\to H$ is a vector $z\in H_1$ so that there is a $\lambda$ with
>   $$L(z) = \lambda \ i(z).$$

Now suppose that $L = A+ B$ where $A:H_1\to H$ is a linear isomorphism and $B : H_1 \to H$ a compact operator. $z$ is an eigenvector of $L$ in the above sense iff:
$$(A+B)\ (z) = \lambda \ i(z) \iff \frac1\lambda z = A^{-1}(i-\lambda^{-1}B)\ (z) \text{ or $(A+B)(z)=0$}$$
ie iff it is an eigenvector to the eigenvalue $\frac1\lambda$ of the compact operator $A^{-1}(i-\lambda^{-1}B): H_1\to H_1$ or if it is in the kernel of $A+B$ (corresponding to eigenvalue $0$). The eigenspaces of the first case are all finite dimensional, since $A^{-1}(i-B)$ is compact and the eigenspace of $0$ is also finite dimensional since $A+B$ is Fredholm.

Comment: Thanks! I think I basically get the idea. But I don't see the equivalence $(A+B)z = \lambda z \iff \lambda^{-1}z = A^{-1}(i - B) z$. Could you further explain?

Comment: I guess it should be $\lambda^{-1}z = A^{-1}(i - \lambda^{-1}B)z$?

Comment: You are right, $\lambda^{-1} z = A^{-1}(i-\lambda^{-1}B)z$ is the correct expression. Now the operator depends on the eigenvalue, but its still a compact operator so the solution space will still be finite dimensional.